# TikZ coordinate that refers to the last "current coordinate"

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

Is it possible, within a TikZ path, to refer to the "current coordinate" as another coordinate?

To make it clear what I want, take this example, which I often end up doing because I don't know better:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
% suppose the "1,1" is a very complicate (possibly unknown) coordinate
% that I would love not to repeat in the code:
\draw (origin) -| (1,1) coordinate (THIS) -- (THIS-|origin);
% This is what I would like to do:
% \draw (origin) -| (1,1) -- (THIS-|origin);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I end up doing is:

```
\draw (origin) -| (1,1) coordinate (THIS) -- (THIS-|origin);
```

because I (say) want to draw a straight line from the current point to what would be a point perpendicular to another.  But it is a *pain* to type `coordinate (THIS)` all the time, and I would like to know if there is a magical internal coordinate that would allow me to do:

```
\draw (origin) -| (1,1) -- (THIS-|origin);
```

and `THIS` would know that it means `1,1`.

Does `THIS` exist, or what I'm doing is the best I can get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use `to` instead of `--`, then the last coordinate is stored in `\tikztostart`, and can be used in the same way you use `THIS`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
% suppose the "1,1" is a very complicate (possibly unknown) coordinate
% that I would love not to repeat in the code:
% This is what I would like to do:
% \draw (origin) -| (1,1) -- (THIS-|origin);
 \draw (origin) -| (1,1)  to (\tikztostart-|origin);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can also use `\THIS`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\def\THIS{\tikztostart}
% suppose the "1,1" is a very complicate (possibly unknown) coordinate
% that I would love not to repeat in the code:
 \draw (origin) -| (1,1)  to (\THIS-|origin);
% This is what I would like to do:
% \draw (origin) -| (1,1) -- (THIS-|origin);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's nice, but it doesn't work for me because I want to continue the path after that (as I said, it's only an example), so it has to work with `--` or other path construction operations

Comment: @LaTeXer You can continue the path after `to` just like after `--`. Try e.g. `\draw (origin) -| (1,1)  to (\tikztostart-|origin) -- ++ (0,1);`.

Comment: I feel stupid (epic facepalm).  Thanks a _LOT_!  I was confusing `to` with `edge`, that stops the path.  Is there any downside of using `to` rather than `--`?

Comment: @LaTeXer As long as the usage is very basic, there is no downside. Once you start to play with keys like `every to`, then `to` will not necessarily be a straight path any more (because you asked for that).  Strictly speaking `to` is also a tiny bit slower than `--` (since among other things it defines `\tikztostart`) but this should not be noticeable.

Comment: Thanks! I'm definitely not expert enough to need `every to`, and speed is not a problem, as I'm using TikZ anyway rather than some reasonable graphics application   Thanks a again

Comment: Hello again!  If you don't mind to take a look: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/572786/171155. Thanks!